# How to have search filter option in multiple dropdown boxes in php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have results which is from particular api. i dont have databse for it. i am using bootstrap table for pagination and column,row alignment. How to have search filter dropdown in client side itself or using php,ajax?.

For example

```
          <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered"        cellspacing="0" width="100%">
           <thead>
             <tr>
                <th>Date</th>
             <th>Caller</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
       [objects] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [customer_name] => dominic

                [start_time] => 2017-06-23 08:40:32+05:30

            )

    [19] => Array
            (
         [customer_name] => celestine

                [start_time] => 2017-06-23 08:40:32+05:30
    )


)
       <?php foreach($json['objects'] as $res){ ?>
             echo '<tr>';
             echo '<td>'.$res['customer_name'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$res['start_time'].'</td>';
             echo '</tr>'   
       <?php } ?>
            </tbody>
       </table>
      <select onchange="functioname()">
       <option>Dominic</option>
      </select>
          <select id="date">
       <option>date</option>
      </select>
```

Comment: You can use datatables https://datatables.net/

Comment: @yes i am using datatables already. right now i need multiple dropdown filter option to show exact result values